# Required:android.app.Fragment error

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on a simple application of tabs but when I do the return I throw this error I do not really know how to solve it, I read something about importing and you put "import android.app.Fragment;" But I already have it that way. I would appreciate if I can resolve my doubt to the point of this error thanks

[image: ERROR]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text, including the error you're getting, and the relevant code from the classes mentioned there.

Comment: Ok ok sorry i'm new to this forum right away i edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I cannot comment yet I will give a full answer altho you haven't provided full details I can guess your problem.

**Answer:**

You probably have different imports on your Fragment class and on your Activity as from your pic on your activity you import this:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

and on your fragment you probably import this:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

meaning its not the same class therefore your ide yells that you have a class mismatch

you should import only one of these on both your activity and fragment..

gl!